# Global variables in two interdependent libraries

Tags: c

Program Main needs to load a plugin A.so.
A.so has a framework it will load another plugin B.so, but B.so needs to use the method defined in A.so.
I know it is possible to create two library A.so and B.so depends on each other.

My question is in the run time (loading time), the global variables in B.so will have 1 copy or 2 copy, that is if A want to use the variables defined in B.so, will it create a new copy?

Comment: Can you post some code, on how you declare/define these variables?

Comment: On Windows or a POSIX (e.g. Linux/OSX) system? What have you tried so far? How did (or didn't) it work?

Comment: Can you post an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reflecting your issue?

Comment: I have accepted the answer from Konrad.

Comment: I just asked this general question, and some people understands and some donot, those who do not understand should not down vote just because you do not understand and you have the point to do down vote.

Comment: if stack overflow let these kinds of destructive behavior flood, i am afraid the end of stack overflow is close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global variables will have one copy *per process*. So as long as your program does not do `fork()` both libraries will operate on the same copy of data.